# iText 7 - com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF startxref not found

Tags: java, io, itext, itext7

We are trying to upgrade from iText 5 to iText 7 and saw few issues. I am getting an exception as "com.itextpdf.io.IOException: PDF startxref not found." inside PdfReader#readPdf() and finally in the caller method getting an exception as *"com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Trailer not found."*.

My use case is creating a PdfReader instance using inputSream and then creating PdfDocument from the reader and passing PdfWriter as a constructor parameter. We are trying to modify existing PDF, and the sample code is as below

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, new PdfWriter(os));
```

What am I doing wrong and how can we fix this issue?

We have a utility method that writes the output stream and creates a new PDF attachment.

Comment: Where does `inputStream` come from? Are you sure you are reading a correct PDF file (i.e. you can open it with an available PDF viewer tool)? Can you share a sample PDF that you have problems with?

Comment: Simply said the error messages mean that your `InputStream` is not positioned at the start of a pdf. I.e. either there is no valid pdf in it at all or the stream already is (partially or completely) read.

Comment: @Alexy-  The pdf is attached as an attachment to an existing table, we have an api through which we read the attachment as an InputStream. I guess, the pdf that was getting created was corrupted. I need to look into that code how I am setting the values in the Pdf Fields.

Comment: I got this issue fixed, I need to close pdfDocument before I am writing attachments from the output stream.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer? That way people can see that the question has been answered (and that they can skip the question).

Comment: I was not closing the stream properly, I created the pdfDocument instance and reading from output stream before closing the pdfDocument. So need to close pdfDocument stream first and then read from output stream to create attachments.

Answer (score 5):

Copying the answer from the comments:

> I got this issue fixed, I need to close `pdfDocument` before I am
>   writing attachments from the output stream.
>
> I was not closing the stream properly, I created the `pdfDocument`
>   instance and reading from output stream before closing the
>   `pdfDocument`. So I need to close `pdfDocument` stream first and then read
>   from output stream to create attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem after add some elements to document (itextpdf 7.2.1), but the instance of PdfDocument was being closed (using a "try with resources"):

```
public static byte[] stampDocument(byte[] fileBytes, Integer startPageNumber) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(bais), new PdfWriter(baos, new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true)))) {
        addStamps(pdf, startPageNumber);
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}

private static void addStamps(PdfDocument pdf, Integer startPageNumber) throws IOException {
    int iStartPageNumber = (startPageNumber == null ? 0 : startPageNumber - 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= pdf.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        Rectangle rect = pdf.getPage(i).getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getPage(i).newContentStreamBefore(), pdf.getPage(i).getResources(), pdf);
        stampPage(canvas, iStartPageNumber + i, rect.getHeight(), rect.getWidth());
    }
}

private static void stampPage(PdfCanvas canvas, int pageNumber, float height, float width) throws IOException { 
    float x = width - 85;
    float y = height - 100;
    
    Rectangle recta = new Rectangle(x, y, 75, 75);
    try (Canvas ca = new Canvas(canvas, recta)) {
        ca.showTextAligned(new Paragraph(new Text(String.valueOf(pageNumber)).setFontSize(FONT_SIZE)), x + (recta.getWidth()/2), recta.getHeight()/2 - FONT_SIZE/2  + y, TextAlignment.CENTER);
    }
    canvas.rectangle(recta);
}
```

The solution was add a Document instance to be closed after add the new elements:

```
public static byte[] stampDocument(byte[] fileBytes, Integer startPageNumber) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(bais), new PdfWriter(baos, new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true)))) {
        Document doc = new Document(pdf);
        addStamps(pdf, startPageNumber);
        doc.close();
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).